# Find missing ids between mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run the following mysql statement, I get **127 rows** returned:

```
SELECT t.strat_id, t.candle_id, t.spot_entry, t.spot_close, t.f,t.fa,t.b,t.we,t.direct,t.date_created,t.date_closed,t.notes,t.results 
            FROM cp_user_trades AS t 
            INNER JOIN candles2 AS c 
                ON t.candle_id = c.id 
            WHERE t.user_login = "user" 
            AND t.active=0 
            AND t.deleted=0 
            ORDER BY t.date_closed DESC
```

When I remove the `INNER JOIN` I get **131 rows** returned:

```
SELECT t.strat_id, t.candle_id, t.spot_entry, t.spot_close, t.f,t.fa,t.b,t.we,t.direct,t.date_created,t.date_closed,t.notes,t.results 
            FROM cp_user_trades AS t 
            WHERE t.user_login = "user" 
            AND t.active=0 
            AND t.deleted=0 
            ORDER BY t.date_closed DESC
```

How can I `SELECT` the **4 rows** that are not being returned in the first statement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming c.ID is the primary key for the candles2 table:

Use a Left Join and add where c.Id is null

Answer (score 1):

To find ids between to tables, I use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select in_cut, in_c2, count(*) as cnt, min(candle_id), max(candle_id)
from (select candle_id, sum(in_cut) as in_cut, sum(in_c2) as in_c2
      from ((select candle_id, 1 as in_cut, 0 as in_c2
             from cp_user_trades
            ) union all
            (select id, 0, 1
             from candles2
            )
           ) cc
      group by candle_id
     ) c
group by in_cut, in_c2;
```

This gives you the three possibilities of ids in the two tables (in the first, in the second, and in both).  It shows whether ids are duplicated in either table, and it gives examples of the ids.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the second query that returns 131 rows, with a subquery that makes it not include the 127 that are found by the other.

```
SELECT t.strat_id, t.candle_id, t.spot_entry, t.spot_close, t.f,t.fa,t.b,t.we,t.direct,t.date_created,t.date_closed,t.notes,t.results 
        FROM cp_user_trades AS t 
        WHERE t.user_login = "user" 
        AND t.strat_id NOT IN (SELECT t.strat_id
            FROM cp_user_trades AS t 
            INNER JOIN candles2 AS c 
            ON t.candle_id = c.id 
            WHERE t.user_login = "user" 
            AND t.active=0 
            AND t.deleted=0 
            ORDER BY t.date_closed DESC)
        AND t.active=0 
        AND t.deleted=0 
        ORDER BY t.date_closed DESC
```

I thought t.strat_id would be the one to exclude. I dont know what the primary(unique) key is, but the line  `AND t.strat_id NOT IN (SELECT t.strat_id` you can replace with t.candle_id if that's what's important. There are other types of joins though, which are definitely more efficient than this.